# concatenated string format in Python?

Tags: python, string, format

I am trying to set the width of a concatenated string. This is what I am trying to do:

```
>>> "{{a}_{b}:<10s}".format(a='xx', b='yy')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: Single '}' encountered in format string
```

I know I can definitely do it by using:

```
>>> "{:<10s}".format("{a}_{b}".format(a='xx', b='yy'))
'xx_yy     '
```

But wondering if there is way that I can do it using a single `format()`.

Comment: @cmidi: no, that's not my wanted result

Comment: perhaps you can self indent `i = 10 - len('xx_yy');y = "{a}_{b}{c}".format(a='xx',b='yy',c=" "*i)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subtract the length of a and b from the padding and pad b, adding one for the `_`:

```
a,  b ='xx','yy'
"{a}_{b:<{ln}s}".format(a=a, b=b, ln= 11 - (len(a)  + len(b)))
```

Or ljust:

```
"{a}_{b}".format(a='xx', b='yy').ljust(10, " ")
```